# change the contrast of an image in DM Scripting

Tags: display, contrast, dm-script

I need to change the contrast of an image by using a script, unfortunately I don't know how to do it, maybe you can help me.

I've searched the help documents, but the results do not give the right answer

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest command for you is most likely `SetLimits`, like in the following example:

```
image img := Realimage("Test",4,256,256)
img = iradius + icol
ShowImage(img)

SetLimits( img, 100, 150 )
```

but you may also want to look at the example in the help documentation in the *imageDisplay* section:

[image]

i.e. this example:

```
// create image
image myImage := Realimage("Test",4,256,256)
myImage = iradius + icol
ShowImage(myImage)

ImageDisplay imageDisp = myImage.ImageGetImageDisplay( 0 )

// get display info
number low, high, bright, contrast
imageDisp.ImageDisplayGetContrastLimits( low, high )
imageDisp.ImageDisplayGetContrastParameters( bright, contrast )

// get color table
Image colorTable := imageDisp.ImageDisplayGetInputColorTable(  ) 

// modify it
colorTable = rgb( icol + 16 * irow, 255 - icol - 16 * irow, 128 )

// apply color table
imageDisp.ImageDisplaySetInputColorTable( colorTable )
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to perform this procedure on a complex image

Comment: @FabianV. For complex images, the "mode" is also important. Use `ImageDisplayGetComplexMode` and `ImageDisplaySetComplexMode` for this.